# Share photos using an application

Tags: facebook, image, web, share

i'm making a web portfolio and i wanna add a button to share a photo on user wall, so when X user click "Share image" it should share the image selected.

I get it using Dialogs, but the image is publish in a very small size and if other wants to see it in full size they've to enter my website.

Don't you know how to make a script so when the user click "Share Image" it works at least similar as when you share a photo inside facebook (like when you share one of your images or something like that) ?

PS: Sorry for my english, i'm not english native and i know i don't speak it very well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Dialogs to upload photos to the user's profile. For this, you will have to use the PHP (or similar SDK) and `POST` data to the API. This [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) will help.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the only way to do something like that? I would prefer not to create an album in every users facebook, because to some of them this could be annoying.

Comment: You don't have to create an album. Facebook will create one for your app if you don't specify an album ID. It's only done when you upload a photo - not before.